# In angular2, how to conditionally register a Pipe?

Tags: angular

Angular2's dependency injection mechanism allows for conditionally declaring Services, here's an example from thoughtram's website:

```
{ 
provide: Engine,
  useFactory: () => {
    if (IS_V8) {
      return new V8Engine();
    } else {
      return new V6Engine();
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar with Pipes?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but you can inject a service into the pipe and delegate to this service.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of those things that happens: finding the answer to a question you have asked on Stackoverflow just a couple of minutes later.

Because angular2's way of configuration is just javascript, it can be pretty simple:

```
environment['development'] ? DevPipe : ProdPipe
```

Another way, as mentioned in the comments, is to inject a conditionally declared Service into the Pipe. That way, you can also consult other Services to decide which Service needs to be injected in the Pipe, something that cannot be done with the first approach.